# Do you suggest HBOT (hyperbaric oxygen therapy) for Crohn's or Ulcerative Colitis?

Tags: gastroenterology, oxygenation

I've been searching about HBOT treatment for a while. I found many sources & researches but couldn't be sure %100. It is a real solution or it can replace with medicines?

For example: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3328239/

The results show us all patients have positive progress. Unfortunately, the doctors don't suggest HBOT as a first option yet.

Do you know anything about this?